# From softmax output to class prediction

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras

Is there an easy way to go from a Softmax output to a class prediction?

For instance,

from this:

```
[0.83128697, 0.06161868, 0.10709436]
```

to this:

```
[1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.argmax` to retrieve the index of max value:

```
import numpy as np
a = [0.83128697, 0.06161868, 0.10709436]

r = np.zeros(len(a)) # a.size if a is a numpy array
r[np.argmax(a)]=1

r
array([1., 0., 0.])
```